# Arduino IDE / Teensy 3 on Ipad

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, teensy

Does anyone know a good IDE for Ipad to write Arduino code and compile it for teensy 3 ?

Answers with different alternatives would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any way to *compile* it on an iPad, but [Textastic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor-for/id383577124) should do the trick for writing the code if you set the syntax highlighting to `C++`.